# SQL: Count records not in subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data for two recipients.

Subscriptions for user 13250626 (recipient A)

[image]

Subscriptions for user 13251076 (recipient B)

[image]

I want to count the number of records, recipient A is registered to that recipient B isnt, my query is not working, returns 0 and I am expecting 1.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  NmsSubscription 
WHERE 
  iRecipientId = 13250626 
  AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 
      1
    FROM 
      NmsSubscription 
    WHERE 
      iRecipientId = 13251076
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  NmsSubscription O
WHERE 
  iRecipientId = 13250626 
  AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 
      1
    FROM 
      NmsSubscription I
    WHERE 
      I.iRecipientId = 13251076 AND I.IServiceID = O.IServiceID
  )
```

Comment: Hi Shah, thanks this works, I tried following the same structure to update the subscriptions that recipient B is not registered to but I am getting an error, `UPDATE 
  NmsSubscription i 
SET 
  i.iRecipientId = 13251076 
WHERE 
  i.iRecipientId = 13250626 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 
      1 
    FROM 
      NmsSubscription O 
    WHERE 
      i.iRecipientId = 13251076 
      AND i.iserviceid = O.iserviceid
  )` 

PGS-220000 PostgreSQL error: ERROR:  column "i" of relation "nmssubscription" does not exist

Comment: @DavidGarcia -- you must omit the alias from the LValue on an update.  It's implicit because you cannot possibly update any other table other than the one declared in "update."  So simply change it from `SET i.iRecipientId = 13251076` to `SET iRecipientId = 13251076`.  However...  can you explain the conditions you are trying to update?

Comment: I want to update recipient B with A's services where B is not already registered to, I tried doing a simple `UPDATE NmsSubscription SET iRecipientId  = 13251076 WHERE iRecipientId  = 13250626` but received an index key violation because A was already registered to some services. PGS-220000 PostgreSQL error: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "nmssubscription_subscription" DETAIL: Key (iserviceid, irecipientid)=(3218161, 13251076) already exists. .

Comment: @DavidGarcia: Please update the question to show what do you expect in terms of output after `UPDATE`.